# Vendor folder not being generated despite being run in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

When loading my AWS Elastic Beanstalk test website using CodeBuild continual deployment, I get this error:

```
Warning: require(/var/app/current/clu/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/clu/public/index.php on line 24 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/app/current/clu/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php') in /var/app/current/clu/public/index.php on line 24
```

It seems like the composer files are not being generated.

However, in the CodeBuild logs, they are.

```
    [Container] 2020/02/24 03:21:34 Running command composer install
    03:21:38
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    03:21:38
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
    03:21:38
    Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
    03:21:38
    Package operations: 89 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    03:21:38
    - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.3.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (100%)
    03:21:38
    - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.1.0): Downloading (connect..
    ...
    Generating optimized autoload files
    > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
    > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
    Discovered Package: [32mfacade/ignition[39m
    Discovered Package: [32mfideloper/proxy[39m
    Discovered Package: [32mlaravel/tinker[39m
    Discovered Package: [32mnesbot/carbon[39m
    Discovered Package: [32mnunomaduro/collision[39m
    [32mPackage manifest generated successfully.[39m
```

This is my buildspec.yml code:

```
version: 0.2
    phases:
      install:
        commands:
        export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
        #Install php7.1
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y  software-properties-common
        LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
        apt-get update
        # Install PHP
        apt-get install -y php7.2\
                 php7.2-ldap \
                 php7.2-xml \
                 php7.2-xmlrpc \
                 php7.2-zip \
                 php7.2-mysql \
                 php7.2-mbstring \
                 php7.2-mcrypt \
                 php7.2-gd \
                 php7.2-readline \
                 php7.2-opcache \
                 php7.2-xdebug \
                 php7.2-dom \
                 php-xdebug \
                 php7.2-curl \
                 unzip

        phpenmod xdebug
        #Install composer
        php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
        php composer-setup.php ;
        php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" ;
        mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Installing composer deps
      - composer install 

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
```

My laravel filesystem does not have the vendor folder as I would like it to be generated via composer install.

Would greatly appreciate a hand, i've tried so many things.. cant get it to generate properly.

I've also checked via ssh and the folder is not there grrr. Its like its being generated elsewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to my buildspec.yml enabled the vendor file to be uploaded to the working server.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
proxy:
  upload-artifacts: yes
  logs: yes
```